# Multiple Two Drop Down Boxes onclick without append

Tags: javascript

this my first attempt at javascript and first post here. I'm trying to display the result of a simple multiplication of values from two drop down boxes. So user selects one value from each, hits the button and gets A*B. It is working how I have it but if they change their answer and try and submit a new number then the second result appends to the first result. I for the life of me cannot get the field to reset. I have tried .replaceWith(result) instead of .append(result) which solves that problem but then the user cannot make the second selection at all.

Any help greatly appreciated! Also, would love to know if it can output with a comma as a thousand separator.

```
      <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
        <label>Select Amount</label>
        <select id="box1" type="select" oninput="calculate()" />
          <option value="choose" selected>Choose</option>
          <option value="15000">$15,000</option>
          <option value="20000">$20,000</option>
          <option value="25000">$25,000</option>
          <option value="30000">$30,000</option>
          <option value="35000">$35,000</option>
        </select>
        <label>Select Type</label>
          <select id="box2" type="select" oninput="calculate()" />
            <option value="x" selected>Choose</option>
            <option value=".21">1</option>
            <option value=".40">2</option>
          </select>
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="multiply">

        <p>
           <strong>here are the results:</strong> 
        </p>
        <h3>
            <strong>$<span id="result2"></span></strong> a week
        </h3>
      </form>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#multiply').click(function(event){


   event.preventDefault();
    var n1=$('#box1').val();
    var n2=$('#box2').val();
    var result=Math.round(n1*n2 /52);


    $('#resultholder2').fadeIn(200);
    $('#number1').append(n1);
    $('#number2').append(n2);
    $('#result2').append(result);
     });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: Hi Again! I am running the following script to add the commas & it is working on <p class="points">12345</p> but not on the output of "results2" any ideas? Script as follows: 

             <script type="text/javascript">

             function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }

            $('.points').each(function() {
                var v_pound = $(this).html();
                v_pound = numberWithCommas(v_pound);

                $(this).html(v_pound)

            })

         </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing great. Just hide previous result before showing new result and use html to show result.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#multiply').click(function(event){


   event.preventDefault();
    var n1=$('#box1').val();
    var n2=$('#box2').val();
    var result=Math.round(n1*n2 /52);
    $("#result2").hide();


    $('#resultholder2').fadeIn(200);
    $('#number1').append(n1);
    $('#number2').append(n2);
    $('#result2').html(result);
     });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! The works great! I spent a couple hours looking for that tweak but couldn't find it! A million thanks!

Comment: great to hear that ..Welcome :)  you can do little bit more by accepting my answer .
If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: @deductibot and here the source to add commas in every 3rd positions. `function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your javascript code.

```
`$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("select").change(function(){
        var n1=$('#box1').val();
        var n2=$('#box2').val();
        var result=Math.round(n1*n2 /52);
        if(!isNaN(result))
            $("#result2").text(result);
     });
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#result2').text('');
```

use this syntax before assigning value to the result element.